# How can I move to the next logical line with the arrow keys?

Tags: motion, keyboard

When I KEY_DOWN, it invokes next-line from simple.el

This next-line moves to the same line, if that line spans multiple lines.

I don't want this to happen.

I want to move to the next logical line;)

I always had it like this before and I haven't changed my config, so something must've changed here?

Answer (score 3):

Just call `next-logical-line`:

> This is identical to `next-line`, except that it always **moves by *logical lines* instead of *visual lines***, ignoring the value of **the variable `line-move-visual`**.

Comment: Indeed, but is it just a matter of binding KEY_DOWN to this? I think I had some issues when I did that.

Comment: @JasonHunter What issues?